# Using propertyChanged in wpf, binding should update on button click

Tags: wpf, mvvm, propertychanged

I have created a errorMessage as a string in my ViewModel. When you get an error or stuff like that, I will use this one to display a message to the user.

**In ViewModel**

I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, also I have created this block:

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

In top of the ViewModel, I have created a string called ErrorMessage.

```
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
```

In the constructor, I have tested it with

```
 ErrorMessage = "Error message";
```

And I can see the text in my view on load.
The problem is when I hit an exception like in a try / catch block and sets the error to a text, it wont get updated.

In the Exception or on a button click, I have tried entering:

```
ErrorMessage = "No rooms with entered settings were found";
```

**The View**

```
<StackPanel Margin="10, 5" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <TextBlock FontFamily="../Fonts/bold.ttf#bold" Height="40" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding ErrorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

If you scroll to the right, you can see that I have binded ErrorMessage and given it the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

What do I need, so I can in my ViewModel, set the ErrorMessage equal to a text on certain scenarios?

Comment: Have you set the DataContext of your view to your ViewModel?

Comment: You need to call NotifyPropertyChanged in the setter of the property, you can't use an Auto property.

Comment: ChrisF, yes, else it wont have worked when I set the ErrorMessage in the constructor, its after when the context is set that I want to change errorMessage based on scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage")  in set method. Extend your property with full get and set accessors implementation (with a private variabile) and then call notifypropertychanged in the set method after privateproperty= value line.

It's important to Notify your view when a property changes.

S

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ErrorMessage` `Property` as:

```
private string errorMessage;

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return errorMessage; }
        set 
        { 
            errorMessage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage");
        }
    }
```